# Angular is taking too much time while using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

We are using AngularJS for our HTML5 app

We have over 300 messages and we want to print all messages on a single page.

We are using this code to print all of the messages using the `data-ng-repeat` directive.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="msg in msgs track by $index">
    <pre ng-bind-html="msg |to_trusted"></pre>
</div>
```

This takes more than 2-3 seconds to complete, which is very slow and creates a very bad user experience.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Could you use something like: http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: Please show an example of a msg.

Comment: @tasseKATT
angular version 1.2.16
and msg example is here 
[
          'this is message one',
          'this is message two',
          'this is message three',.....
]

Comment: first of all get rid of filter `| to_trusted`.

Comment: Can msgs be added/deleted after printed? Can a msg change after printed? Bottom line - are the data bindings needed?

Comment: You should look for DOM virtualization or a pager. Just show relevant information on to the screen